# Trimmomatic-0.39 error message "Unknown option -baseout ..."

Tags: zsh, bioinformatics, sequencing

I have used Trimmomatic-0.39 few times already for trimming some sequencing data. This time I tried the option `-baseout` as stated in the manual but it does not recognise it as a valid option and the command does not run. If I run the command, as I usually I do with all the output files listed, it works though.

I type in the command line:

```
java -jar trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -phred33 -trimlog trimmed_file18_log.log -baseout file18.fastq.gz file18-R1.fastq.gz file18-R2.fastq.gz ILLUMINACLIP:NexteraPE-PE.fa:2:30:10 MAXINFO:25:0.2 MINLEN:20
```

What I get back is:

```
Unknown option -baseout file18.fastq.gz
Usage: 
  PE [-version] [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-summary <statsSummaryFile>] [-quiet] [-validatePairs] [-basein <inputBase> | <inputFile1> <inputFile2>] [-baseout <outputBase> | <outputFile1P> <outputFile1U> <outputFile2P> <outputFile2U>] <trimmer1>...
   or: .....
```

I get back the same error message even if I move the '-baseout file18.fastq.gz' option after '...jar PE' and before the list of all the other options.

Comment: I gave your command a quick test and it appears to run successfully. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: ok @Steve I use JDK 17. To be more specific, openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18